# SQL to derive package and Item details

Tags: hive, hiveql

We have a requirement, where we get package details having list of items in one table. and in other table we have these items.

Sample Data

Package Details.

```
PackName|ItemName|ItemQuantity
1|AA|10
1|AB|20
1|AC|30
2|BC|40
2|BD|50
2|BE|60
2|BF|70
```

Item Received

```
ItemName|ItemQuantity
AA|10
AB|20
AC|30
AA|10
AB|20
AC|30
BC|40
BD|50
BE|60
BF|70
AA|10
AB|20
BE|60
BF|70
```

Desired Output

Output-1

```
ItemName|ItemQuantity|Is Package
AA|10|1
AB|20|1
AC|30|1
AA|10|1
AB|20|1
AC|30|1
BC|40|1
BD|50|1
BE|60|1
BF|70|1
AA|10|0
AB|20|0
BE|60|0
BF|70|0
```

Output-2

```
PackName|TotalPacks
1|2
2|1
```

Output1 --> if we receive all the items in a pack then we need to derive IsPackage as 1 or else 0

Output2 --> We need to update total Packs which were shipped, in our case since we have received 2 packs of A and 1 B.

Comment: Your data are not normalized.  But, more to the point: your question is unclear.  Why, for example, do the row tuples (ItemName|ItemQuantity) of AA|10, AB|20, BE|60 show up with an "Is Package" value of first "1" and then "0".  What's the difference?

Comment: PackName1 consists of 3 items, so in items if we have all 3 items with same quantity then only we will mark IsPackage value as 1, if there is difference in number of items or the quantity specified in package details then IsPackage value will be 0.

Comment: ok.  so what's the issue?  Sounds like a straight-forward problem: match the set of items received to the possible package combinations, yes?